# Push rejected to herokuapp

Tags: django, git, heroku

I am trying to host my dango rest app on heroku. When i run

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the error log

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.4 (you 
are using python-3.6.3, which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest 
version (python-3.6.4).
remote:        Learn More: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r 
/tmp/build_76cc8692e5f28e80c394427df6e4d58b/requirements.txt (line 
9))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the 
requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r / 
tmp/build_76cc8692e5f28e80c394427df6e4d58b/requirements.txt (line 9)) 
(from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for pkg-
resources==0.0.0 (from -r 
/tmp/build_76cc8692e5f28e80c394427df6e4d58b/requirements.txt (line 
9))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
```

The requirements.txt file is

```
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.11.2
django-rest-auth==0.9.2
djangorestframework==3.6.4
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.2.0
psycopg2==2.7.3
PyJWT==1.5.3
pytz==2017.2
six==1.11.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

push is rejected by heroku. please help.

Comment: its clearly showing Could not find a version that satisfies the 
requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0, then where is the problem? remove that package name from the text file and check again

Comment: Yu have to specify the correct version in your runtime.txt.

Comment: @CodeWizard i have added requirements.txt. ps check

Comment: @Exprator remove that package from where? please read the log properly.

Answer (score 0):

Does your local `requirements.txt` match `requirements.txt` from `master` branch?

I had the same problem and finaly I realized that my master branch had that `pkg-resources` line in `requirements.txt` while my local copy hadn't. I deleted that line from `requirements.txt`, did `git commit`, `git push` and next time I tried to push my app to heroku I succeed.